# Is it possible to use JavaScript or PHP in static FBML?

Tags: facebook, fbml

Is there some way to embed JavaScript or PHP code in static FBML on Facebook?

Comment: Wouldn't it be an enormous security hole if you could?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS) in FBML, and you certainly can use PHP to *generate* FBML and FBJS if you so choose.

But that's only for applications and application tabs.

Static FBML like for FBML Boxes and such - you cannot.